# Add a new specific line in file python

Tags: python, file, file-management

I have multiple files in folder X which all look like this: [image]

I want to rewrite the files in Y, copy paste the line 'Time' under 'Time', rename it to 'TimeDif' and in 'Description' I want to calculate td: (ct - tt).

So the file has to look like this:[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9ZWc.png]

This is the code I have right now:

```
import os
import fileinput

src = r'c:\data\KK\Desktop\X'
dst = r'c:\data\KK\Desktop\Y'

for a in os.listdir(src):
    path = os.path.join(src, a)
    pathz = os.path.join(dst, a)
    print(pathz)

    with (path, 'r') as opener, open (pathz, 'w') as quiter:
        for line in fileinput.FileInput(opener, inplace=1):
            if 'Time' in line:
                line = line.rstrip()
                line = line.rename('TimeDif')
```

Comment: Maybe you could change the file format to a .csv and use pandas instead for better management.

Comment: Since you are called ManCity10, I'll help you. :-) Especially now when you have the code up.

Your problem is in "rename". There is no such function, and in fact the text lines you get don't have names. You probably want `replace()`, instead, where you replace the "Time" text with "TimeDif".

You also need to parse the line to get the times out and calculate the diff.

Comment: Instead of an image, can you send a link to an example file? What field separator do you use in the files? Tabs?

Comment: I have added my code to the question guys. @LennartRegebro thoughts on coming Wednesday?

Comment: @ManCity10 Everything is up in the air now. Playing for an empty stadium etc, it's gonna be weird. No guarantees.

Comment: @LennartRegebro True we'l see what happens. Lets talk about code before they kick us out :-).  So replacing rename with Replace is the 1st step. What do you mean by your last line 'you also need to parse...' Can you show me in code what you mean?

Comment: @ePi272314 you can see my files in my question, as you can see I use white spaces as field seperators.

Comment: @ManCity10 You can for example split the line on `"tt: ` and then again on `ct: ` so that you get the two timestamps. Then you can use `datetime.datetime.datetime.strptime()` to parse the timestamps into DateTime objects. Then you can just subtract one from the other, and you get a TimeDelta object, where you can get the number of seconds on difference.